# Some basic questions about cutting closed orientable surfaces (torus, etc.)

Tags: general-topology

I've been trying to wrap my head around basic topological properties of "simple" surfaces - closed orientable surfaces of genus $n$, i.e. spheres with $n$ holes, and I have a number of probably very basic questions that I hope someone is kind enough to answer.

I'm interested in understanding *cutting along closed non-self-intersecting circles*. I don't know how its properly called, but on the surface I call the "sides" induced by the cut (which can be glued) *borders*. A *hole* to me is a surface patch that glues two circular open borders on the "main" sphere. If I understand correctly, I can normalize all surfaces constructed here into such a central main sphere, and $n$ such holes.

1. Are both of these ways of "adding a handle" to create a "hole" equivalent / well defined - gluing two spheres with two borders vs. gluing two borders of the same surface? (My intuition is yes?)
2. If I cut a torus going *once* around its hole, I get back my sphere with two borders. If I cut a torus going *twice* (ore more) around its hole, I get back a sphere with just one border. Is there an intuitive explanation for that? I kind of understood this by drawing the cut on the fundamental polygon of the torus and it "made sense" in a geometric way, but what is the actual reason?
3. If I cut along any non-contractible loop going through any combination of holes *at most once* - I reduce the genus by 1 and get two open borders. Is this correct?
4. I could not really wrap my head around the general case - cutting along a loop that goes through different holes possibly many times. What is the result in that case?
5. When I draw a loop going twice between two different holes - it looks like a Möbius strip. How does winding around holes of an orientable surface result in a Möbius strip?
6. Is there some established diagrammatic visual notation to visualize and reason about such objects and operations? I've been trying to come up with some 2D "circles connected by wires" notation and rules to manipulate it, but can't help but wonder if there is a good representation that sits between 3D renderings and pure 1-dimensional abstract symbolic algebra? Or is there some nice software to play around with such things?

I know that's probably a lot to unpack, so thanks a lot in advance for your time and patience!

Comment: Did you consider reading a textbook on topology of surfaces? There are many...

Comment: I have not a pure math background and I dive into various topics just for fun in my limited free time. If you think there is a good introduction-level textbook balancing the line between rigor and intuition and that should resolve all my questions, than I'm happy to get a suggestion.

Comment: You can try first reading here: https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~jean/surfclass-n.pdf or/and https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/surgery/zeeman.pdf

Comment: Both look like good starting points, thanks!